# dynamically change UIKeyboards return key

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have two UITextfield the user enters his name into the first and email into the second. I would like to know how to change the UIKeyboards return key depending if the name text field has an entry or not.

For instance if nametextfield is empty then I would like the UIkeyboard return key to be Next
else if the nametextfield has an entry in it then when the user selects the email text field I would like the return key to be submit.

Is this possible? if so how would I go about accomplishing it? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have return key customized to prefixed values that you can see in `UIReturnKeyType` enum for each `UITextField`.

```
textFieldName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
textFieldEmail.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.

Comment: oh yup thats pretty much it, but I am not sure where to put this code?

Comment: for instance what method is called when you enter the uitextfield? or is there another place I can put it?

Comment: you usually put it in viewDidLoad of your view controller, but depends on your specific case (are your text fields fully created at that time or do you do it at a later stage, for example).

Comment: my textfields are created as soon as the app loads.. but its not till later that the user enteres a name and email.. the thing I am confused by is how do i decide what return button to show at viewdid load if i dont know if a name is entered untill the user enteres it.... I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

You have a chance to set up keyboard characteristics in the **UITextFieldDelegate Protocol** method **textFieldShouldBeginEditing:** which is called before the text field becomes the first responder (indeed to decide if it **may** become the first responder).  If you don't already have a delegate for the text field(s) in question you would have to assign one and implement at least that method.  Presumably the same object handling the text field could hold the delegate methods.  The following implementation sets the return key to "Search".

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    return YES;
}
```

You'd have to look at the contents of your text fields to decide what value to use.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the textField.returnKeyType property.

you can check out all the available options here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIReturnKeyType

Answer (score 1):

textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;