# How to change the return type of keyboard

Tags: ios

How to change the return type of the appeared keyboard by clicking the button on screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically change UIKeyboards return key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075987/dynamically-change-uikeyboards-return-key)

Comment: @sreekanthk...I Went with that all. what I wanted is to change the return key of the keyboard by clicking on a checkbox which is of UIButton type and not by entering text in the textfield

Comment: write an action to that button to change the keyboard return key at wht textfield it is editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to your header file

and you can use

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change 'Return' into these predefined labels with the `returnKeyType` property:

- Return (default)
- Go
- Google
- Join
- Next
- Route
- Search
- Send
- Yahoo
- Done
- Emergency Call